# AWS S3 bucket policy to external account denies access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have created an S3 bucket which we will call `mytest-bucket` where I am trying to grant access to the bucket and its objects to an **IAM user at a different company**, not within my organization. The user, which we call `Bob` has given me their account ID, IAM username, and canonical ID. I've done the following to attempt to grant `Bob` access:

**1) I have set the bucket policy for `mytest-bucket` as such:**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:root",
                    "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:user/Bob"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:*",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mytest-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::mytest-bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**2) I have set my `Individual Block Public Access settings for this bucket` to the following:**
[image]

**3) I have also granted `List, Write` ACL permissions to the External account using the Canonical ID provided, as well as `Read, Write` Bucket ACL permissions.** For object ownership, I have `ACLs are enabled and can be used to grand access to this bucket and its objects.`

Yet, still, `Bob` is unable to both 1) see the bucket listed under their account, 2) access any objects or the bucket itself due to Access Denied error.

- Is there something I can change in the above configuration to provide `Bob` access to this one bucket and it's objects?
- How can I help them get access?

Edit: `Bob` will not be uploading objects, but only reading and downloading objects from this bucket.

Comment: can you confirm that 1111111111 is the account number where bob is? Also, make sure that Bob's permission is right.

Comment: @AnthonyB. I have confirmed the account number. Can you clarify what you mean by 'make sure Bob's permission is right'? I know they have S3 access on their IAM role in general.

Comment: 1. Will never happen AFAIK. You'll want your policy to enforce bucket-owner-full-control ACL or it will cause problems if account B uploads. If using encrpytion account B also needs access to the KMS key.

Comment: @srj8402, you might consider reading this: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cross-account-access-s3/

Comment: @jordanm Account B or 'Bob' is not uploading, but only reading/downloading the objects in the bucket I intend to give them access to.

Comment: @AnthonyB. I've read the article, are you referring to "Give the IAM role in Account B permission to download (GET Object) and upload (PUT Object) objects to and from a specific bucket"? I can't manage their IAM role so do I have to tell them to apply these permissions themselves?

Comment: Yes, you need to make sure they have the permission to do S3 operations on any bucket. Or if not any, then at least yours.

Comment: **Side-comment:** Be very, very careful! Your above policy is granting Bob `s3:*` permission on the bucket, which includes the ability to delete objects, change permissions on the bucket and even delete the whole bucket!

Comment: **How is Bob attempting to access the bucket?** Is Bob using the S3 management console, or the AWS CLI (or something else)? Please show us the _exact_ error message that Bob is receiving, and _where_ he is receiving it (eg a screenshot of the console, or an error message from the AWS CLI).

Comment: The bucket policy alone should be sufficient for granting Bob the necessary permissions -- there is no need to grant ACL permissions too. In fact, these days AWS recommends turning off ACLs on buckets: [Amazon S3 Object Ownership can now disable access control lists to simplify access management for data in S3](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/11/amazon-s3-object-ownership-simplify-access-management-data-s3/)

Answer (score 0):

You say that "bob is unable to see the bucket listed under their account". This is **normal** -- the bucket does not belong to his account, so it will not be listed when he uses the S3 management console. However, **Bob should be able to access it when using the AWS CLI**, such as:

```
aws s3 ls s3://mytest-bucket
```

If Bob really wants to see it in the console, he can 'cheat' by using a URL that will show the bucket, but Bob would need to paste the URL directly rather than going through the bucket hierarchy. To demonstrate, here is a URL that would normally show a bucket:

```
https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/mytest-bucket
```

You can **change the bucket name at the end** to 'jump' directly to a desired bucket.